# If $A = \{ a \}$, $B = \{ b, c \}$ and $C = \{ d,e,f,g,h,i,j \}$, find (i) $P(A \times B)$; (ii) $|P(B \times C)|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A = \{ a \}$, $B = \{ b, c \}$ and $C = \{ d,e,f,g,h,i,j \}$, find

(i) $P(A \times B)$;

(ii) $|P(B \times C)|$.

$A \times B = \{ (a, b), (a, c) \}$

$P(A \times B) = \{ \emptyset, \{ (a, b) \}, \{ (a, c) \}, \{ (a, b), (a, c) \} \}$

$|B \times C| = |B| \times |C| = 14$. So I think that $|P(B \times C)| = 2^{14}$.

Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have answered the question correctly.

In general, $P(X)=2^{|X|}$ where $P(X)$ denote the power set of $X$ because for each possible subset we decide if it is in that particular subset.